# HP Vertica installation

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, database, hp

I like to know which version of HP vertica will suit for cento os 7.1 version. I'm facing below mentioned issue during vertica 8.1 installation on cento os 7.1.

Issues faced:

```
WARN (N0010): //my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#cshid=N0010
    Linux iptables (firewall) has some non-trivial rules in tables: filter
WARN (S0112): //my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#cshid=S0112
    vm.swappiness is higher than recommended: your 60 > 1
FAIL (S0020): //my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#cshid=S0020
    Readahead size of xvda (/dev/xvda1) is too low for typical systems: 256
    < 2048
FAIL (S0180): https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#cshid=S0180
    Insufficient swap size. Need 2.00 GB, have 0.00 GB
FAIL (S0321): https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#cshid=S0321
    RHEL/Centos 7.1, 7.2 not supported, please use RHEL/Centos 7.3 or later

System prerequisites failed.  Threshold = WARN
    Hint: Fix above failures or use --failure-threshold

Installation FAILED with errors.
```

Note: Upgrading OS is not possible. So like to know alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you do something radical like reading the sections of the manual the installer points you at and use the suggestions there to come to  the correct settings and a supported environment.

But to start with the most obvious one:

> RHEL/Centos 7.1, 7.2 not supported, please use RHEL/Centos 7.3 or later

Use a supported OS (which you can easily achieve with `yum update`) RHEL 7.1 was released over two years ago and is hopelessly out of date and insecure.

> Note: Upgrading OS is not possible.

Then be just as strict and say the installing Vertica is not possible. But have you thought about down-grading to a supported RHEL 6 version instead?

If you really need to you can fake a specific RHEL version by upgrading only the redhat-release package or by editing the `/etc/redhat-release` file.

Comment: Is there any possibilities to get vertica particular version which suits for cento 7.1 .. I mean from any third party sites.